# Coco2d MoveBy at Bezier Speed

Tags: c++, performance, cocos2d-x, bezier, path-finding

I'd like to move a sprite along a path at a variable speed. Ideally, I want to move along a bezier path at a (different) bezier speed, meaning it eases along the path and does NOT move at a constant speed. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Something like:

```
ccBezierConfig path; // With it's points
ccBezierConfig speed; // With it's points
BezierBy::create(duration, path, speed);
```

Obviously that's pseudo code, but hopefully that makes sense. I'd like to perform a moving animation at a bezier speed.

Comment: to be more precise: you want a custom traversal speed, not "bezier speed". There is one, and only one, traversal speed function for a Bezier curve, based on linear increments of the control variable, so if you're talking about "easing", that's just as difference from the true Bezier traversal speed as constant speed is.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about easing, but not the built-in EaseIn, EaseOut, EaseInOut function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there IS a built in function for this. (As I thought- I just couldn't find it. -_-)

For anybody that may stumble upon this in the future (or, you know, me in 6 months) I used the JumpBy/JumpTo.

```
JumpBy::create(float duration, const cocos2d::Vec2 &position, float height, int jumps)
```

The `duration` is the amount of time it takes to complete the path.
The `position` is the END point of the path. 
The `height` is the cresting point of the path, and the `jump` should normally be set to 1 for an effect like mine, but increasing it will give you a 'bouncing' effect.